# How to combine a Dart project with PHP?

Tags: php, dart, dart-editor

I am a very newbie to Dart. The today's question is: How to combine a PHP project with Dart code? The most typical example is passing `json_encoded` variables to JavaScript or Dart with `<?php echo ?>`, or, sometimes, including some `echo's` in the HTML code. But if I work with the Dart editor and test in Chromium, I have no access to my locally running PHP server (e.g. Xampp).

How should I deal with that, what is the practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't generate content or scripts in PHP to be displayed by Dart when using Dart. Dart is best used with Single Page Application Frameworks. (AngularDart, PolymerDart)

Idealy, you build the entire client code in Dart. Dart communicates with the server using HTTP requests or WebSocket to send or fetch the data. The data format is usually JSON but can also be any other format (images, audio, video, ...). Only data is sent between Dart client and PHP server.

When you build Dart to JavaScript the generated output can be integrated with your PHP like some other static content (HTML, Images, ...).

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it would be interesting as well to know, how to get some json data immediately at loading script, not asynchrously.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example to discuss? If you want to include data from a database you have to load the Dart page in the browser and when the script is invoked it can make a request to the server. I think it would work to embed `<?php echo ?>` in the HTML and let PHP process them but I guess the development story would be complicated a lot if you want to work this way.

Comment: Can't it easily be implemented with dart-js-interop library?

Comment: if you use `<?php echo?>` you can embed some JavaScript and you can access this JavaScript from Dart, but that has no influence to the 'development story'. I think what you try to do is premature optimization. I would go with an Ajax-request and if the app is working fine otherwise but this causes a delay you want to avoid try to optimize it away but not when you start developing.

Comment: Ok well I understand. Maybe it would be nice to add this feature in the future (for example in Chromium, some way); I guess it would be very handy to be able to pass some data before bootstrapping the app. I am pretty surprised that nobody has asked this before (nothing found on Google)

Comment: This is because a Dart browser app doesn't work this way. To make this work you need a server that processes the HTML files. For a Dart app you don't need a server that understands specific tags like `<? ?>`. For a web server a Dart app is like a static html file or an image or any static file. If the client requests a specific file the server delivers it and doesn't care at all what file it is of if it should do something preprocessing before delivering.

Comment: As stated above, you **can** do it by injecting JavaScript. A similar approach doesn't work with Dart because Dart must be compiled before it is delivered and this means that the entire application must be compiled. You can't compile a simple snipped and add it later to the already compiled application. And because compilation is slow you can't do it on the fly. I think it just isn't worth the hassle. Dart is targeted on bigger applications where such microoptimization doesn't make a notable difference.